# Clarifai custom model

Tags: java, spring-boot, metadata, image-recognition, clarifai

I'm trained a custom model for image recognition and it works well along with response of the concept and value i tried to get the custom meta data which i added to the concepts but unable to get the meta data it return null while debugging. How do i get the custom meta data along with the response?

```
  for (BufferedImage bufferedImage : croppedImages)
               {
                   try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                       ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", byteArrayOutputStream);

                       byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
//                       byte[] bytes = image.getBytes();
                       ByteString imageContent = ByteString.copyFrom(bytes);

                       Input input = Input.newBuilder()
                               .setData(Data.newBuilder()
                                       .setImage(com.clarifai.grpc.api.Image.newBuilder()
                                               .setBase64(imageContent)
                                               .build())
                                       .build()).build();
                       inputs.add(input);
                   }catch (IOException e) {
                       System.err.println("Error processing cropped image: " + e.getMessage());
                   }
               }
        }
        MultiOutputResponse postModelOuputResponse = stub.postModelOutputs(
                PostModelOutputsRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setUserAppId(UserAppIDSet.newBuilder().setUserId(USER_ID).setAppId(APP_ID))
                        .setModelId(MODEL_ID)
                        .setVersionId(MODEL_VERSION_ID)
                        .addAllInputs(inputs)
                        .build()
        );

        if (postModelOuputResponse.getStatus().getCode() != StatusCode.SUCCESS)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("post model output failed, status: "+postModelOuputResponse.getStatus());
        }


        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Output output : postModelOuputResponse.getOutputsList()) {
            System.out.println("meta "+output.getData().getMetadata().getFieldsMap());
            for (Concept concept : output.getData().getConceptsList()) {

                if (concept.getValue()*100 >= 70.00) {
                    System.out.printf("%s %.2f%n", concept.getName(), concept.getValue());
                    System.out.println(concept.getValue() * 100);


                    Product product = productRepository.findByKeyName(concept.getName());
                    if (product == null)
                        continue;
                    product.setConfidenceScore(String.valueOf(concept.getValue()*100));
                    Serializable serializable = product.name != null ? productList.add(product) : "";
                }
            }
        }
```

Need to get the meta data along with the response